# Angular looping using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

I'm a beginner in Angular, I'm developing a website in Angular 8 and i've this in one of my page:

```js
    const gridTableCells = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-table > div');
    gridTableCells.forEach((cell) => {
      const orderNum = cell.getAttribute('order');
      (orderNum % 2 !== 0) && (cell.className = '--is-striped');
    });
```

```css
/* Grid Table */
.grid-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid red;
    margin: 2em 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(7, auto);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .grid-table > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .grid-table > div.--is-striped {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
  .grid-table div.thead {
      background-color: #eee;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .grid-table div a {
      margin-right: 1em;
  }
```

```html
    <!-- Year-wise Grid Table -->
<div class="grid-table">
    <div order="1" class="thead">Year</div>
    <div order="2"><p>2020</p></div>
    <div order="3"><p>2019</p></div>
    <div order="4"><p>2018</p></div>
    <div order="5"><p>2017</p></div>
    <div order="6"><p>2016</p></div>
    <div order="7"><p>2010</p></div>

    <div order="1" class="thead">some text</div>
    <div order="2"><p>some text</p></div>
    <div order="3"><p>some text</p></div>
    <div order="4"><p>some text</p></div>
    <div order="5"><p>some text</p></div>
    <div order="6"><p>some text</p></div>
    <div order="7"><p>some text</p></div>

    <div order="1" class="thead">Company</div>
    <div order="2">
        <a class="external" href="#">some text</a>, <a class="external" href="#">some text</a>, <a class="external" href="#">some text</a>
        
    </div>
    <div order="3"><a class="external" href="#">some text</a>, <a class="external" href="#">some text</a></div>
    <div order="4"><a class="external" href="#">some text</a></div>
    <div order="5"><a class="external" href="#">some text</a></div>
    <div order="6"><a class="external" href="#">some text</a>, <a class="external" href="#">some text</a></div>
    <div order="7"><a class="external" href="#">some text</a></div>
  </div>
<!-- /Year-wise Grid Table -->
```

Now my question is I don't this to be just static in my component.html which produces a Data Table but instead of having a static HTML code, I want to loop it using *ngFor, I don't know how to do it? Any help? or any reference url where i can learn from?

Comment: For this particular requirement, are you sure actually want to apply a separate css class instead of just use a css selector for the same effect like `div[order]:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f2f2f2 }` and avoid the extra process all together? Also `order` isn't a valid attribute, you should probably use `data-order` as your attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wreopf) for you that uses Angular's [Mat Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) in the way you wanted your table. Note how I used the `ngfor` directive for showing links in the company column.

**table.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let link of element.company">
    <a href={{link.link}}>{{link.link_text}}</a>
</div>
```

I'd suggest you to go through the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) for learning new directives or concepts.

Comment: That worked but you have refactored my code, i.e. I'm using CSS Grid for table layout and you have used HTML <Table> tags. Your solution gave me an idea of how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can learn that in angular site:
https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: This is better suited as a comment than an actual answer.

Comment: i cant comment because my low reputation , sry